# Why is the "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" option inactive?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, remote-access

I am trying to enable "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" so I can trigger a build remotely. But when I go to "Configure" and want to check the checkbox, it is greyed out, and it doesn't say why. I've been Googling like mad, and can't find anything on it anywhere.

[image]

Update:

I notice everything is greyed out. All tutorials I can find they say I should be able to simply tick it on from here. But it's obviously not that easy. Maybe because I need to define it in my `Jenkinsfile`? If so, how?

When I go to edit Build Triggers, I notice it says "View configuration", not "Edit configuration"

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Disappointed there is not an answer yet.